# SQL Server : get IN value for which it was found that row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm having difficulties for solving this problem. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (ver. 12.0.4100.1).

I have two tables `contacts` and `business`. I have an array of contact usernames. I'm fetching a business list from this username array with a subquery in the `WHERE`, like this:

```
SELECT business.id, business.name, business.notes
FROM business
WHERE business.id IN (SELECT contacts.business_id
                      FROM contacts
                      WHERE contacts.username IN ('username1', 'username2', 'username3'))
```

This query is working correctly, but I can't figure out how to select also the value for which every row was found; for example: if I fetch the business from the contact with username 'username1', I want to fetch it and see the result:

```
business.id = 1
business.name = 'Business 1'
business.notes = 'Notes from business 1.'
contacts.username = 'username1'
```

Getting that result, I could see easily from what contact came every business.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: There may be more than one contact for every business, so doing an `INNER JOIN` would return duplicated business results for every contact. I want to know exactly what contact was the one which was selected on the subquery.

Comment: `INNER JOIN` the `contacts` table on the common business id.

Comment: There may be more than one contact for every business, so doing an `INNER JOIN` would return duplicated business results for every contact. I want to know exactly what contact was the one which was selected on the subquery.

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry! That way is not repeating results, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for a `join`:

```
SELECT b.id, b.name, b.notes, c.username
FROM business b JOIN
     contacts c
     ON b.id = c.business_id
WHERE c.username IN ('username1', 'username2', 'username3');
```

Comment: The problem here is that there may be more than one contact for every business, so doing an `INNER JOIN` would return duplicated business results for every contact. I want to know exactly what contact was the one which was selected on the subquery.

Comment: @devrique . . . This only chooses contacts that are in your list.  It does not produce a row for every contact.  If a business matches multiple contacts, which do you want to choose?

Comment: Oops, sorry! I'm a bit dense today. It's true that this way is not repeating business results. I thought I tried it already that way and it didn't work. Thank you so much! :)